# Prolog - is built-in command

Tags: prolog

I don't understand, why the second doesn't work. I thought in first example, the II variable isn't needed, but looks like it is, but i don't know why?
If i call `findex([1,2,5,4], 5, I)`, than first example returns correct index `3` and second returns `false`. Can somebody help me to understand it?

```
findex([X|_], X, 1).
findex([_|T], MAX, INDEX) :- findex(T, MAX, II), INDEX is II +1.

findex([X|_], X, 1).
findex([_|T], MAX, INDEX) :- findex(T, MAX, INDEX), INDEX is INDEX +1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example will not work.

The key thing to understand is that both `INDEX`s in `INDEX is INDEX +1` are the same, they must have the same value. It's like variables in algebra - all Xs in an equation means the same value.

Another way to think of it is that all variables in Prolog are "assign once" variables: after a variable has its value it can't be changed without backtracking.